# How to prevent weird behavior when dragging element out of browser right and bottom border - Angular 7?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, angular7

I am using Drag and Drop feature in Angular 7, but when I drag a `div` out of right or bottom border of browser, the page get extended and it looks very ugly.

But if I drag the `div` out of left or top border, the div just get hidden, and I think this is a more reasonable behavior.

Same thing happens in both Chrome and Firefox.

You can try this out on  [Angular Material official site.](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview)

[image]

Is there a way to make the right/bottom direction behavior the same as left/top?

Comment: It's a browser feature. But looking at your page, it seems [this](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview#restricting-movement-within-an-element)  would be appropriate to you.

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks for your comment, I understand the drag&drop could be restricted within a particular area. I just don't want that way in my work:)

Comment: Well... that's what your question is asking for isn't it? Besides, if it doesn't move toward top and left it's because there is probably nothing to scroll in these directions. Otherwise, it would scroll the same way

Comment: @Kaiido Actually there is a tiny difference, if I use drag&drop boundary, the div will hit a hard stop on the right/bottom direction. The thing i ask for is how to prevent the page from extending.

Comment: The page is not extending, it's scrolling and this is the default browser's behavior. Now, to prevent this, you can very well make your scrolling element's `overflow` to hidden when you are dragging something. But you could also probably just use the `cdkDragBoundary` with an element that has a fixed position, and the size of your viewport

Comment: Ok, i will try `overflow:hidden`

Answer (score 0):

Set css `overflow-x: hidden` on `<body>` resolved the right border over scroll issue.

But can not do it on `y` direction, it will freeze the up/down scroll.

Thanks to @Kaiido's insight.